# C++ Builder Web Image To TImage control

Tags: delphi, c++builder, rad

Someone Please Help me, How to use this code in C++ builder?
   I want to Get a image from web To TImage Control.

```
 uses
  GIFImg;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  GIf: TGIFImage;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  GIf := TGIFImage.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);       
    Gif.LoadFromStream(MS);
    img1.Picture.Assign(GIF);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(GIF);
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <GIFImg.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm1::btn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemoryStream *MS = new TMemoryStream;
    TGIFImage *GIf = new TGIFImage;
    try
    {
        IdHTTP1->Get("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif", MS);
        MS->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);       
        Gif->LoadFromStream(MS);
        img1->Picture->Assign(Gif);
    }
    __finally
    {
        FreeAndNil(GIF);
        FreeAndNil(MS);
    }
}
```